# Best way to updating a list in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, nosql

I have documents with list elements in mongodb. When i get an input to a program, I need to retrieve the document for the given id, get the list element from document and check if the value is there already. If it is not there, need to update that list in the particular document and update db.

What is the best way to do it in MongoDB java driver? I'm thinking of :

- retrieving the document and getting the list element
- Check for the value. If it is not there add it to the list
- Create a BasicDBObject with "$set" operator for that list (say updatedList)
- finally, collection.update(searchQuery, updatedList);

Please let me know the best way to do this considering performance. Can i use $addToSet for this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `$addToSet` in this scenario.

Than fetching docs, doing manipulation all by oneself, I would prefer to let mongo do the things (if possible), like in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit in the list of an element. You can use $each

Comment: This should be a comment instead. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)